# Center form submit buttons HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, center, alignment

I'm having troubles centering my HTML form submit buttons in CSS.

Right now I'm using:

```
    <input value="Search" title="Search" type="submit" id="btn_s">
    <input value="I'm Feeling Lucky" title="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="lucky" type="submit" id="btn_i">
```

with this CSS content

```
#btn_s{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#btn_i {
    width: 125px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And it's not doing anything. I know I'm probably doing something stupid wrong. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/rJxQC/

i just wrapped a div around them and made it align center. then you don't need any css on the buttons to center them.

```
<div class="buttonHolder">
  <input value="Search" title="Search" type="submit" id="btn_s"> 
  <input value="I'm Feeling Lucky" title="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="lucky" type="submit" id="btn_i">
</div>

.buttonHolder{ text-align: center; }
```

Comment: actually, the downside of this solution is that holder div centers *everything* in it, including text and children and children of children... so it's usually better to use 'margin: 0 auto' on single elements, when we don't want the entire container centered - and, as pointed out, you can achieve that with block elements. Still, occasionally I use centering like this, so it's -0 from me, since you're not wrong...

Comment: Works perfectly for me when I used it for a CSS styled button link. Wrap the <a href> with the div and class and it should work perfectly without affecting different classes.

Answer (score 37):

Input elements are inline by default. Add `display:block` to get the margins to apply. This will, however, break the buttons onto two separate lines. Use a wrapping `<div>` with `text-align: center` as suggested by others to get them on the same line.

Comment: The thing I really like about this answer is that it explains why the problem was happening in the first place.

Answer (score 20):

I see a few answers here, most of them complicated or with some cons (additional divs, text-align doesn't work because of display: inline-block). I think this is the simplest and problem-free solution:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <!-- Rows -->
    <tr>
        <td>E-MAIL</td>
        <td><input name="email" type="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Register!" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, this is best solution, thanks! +1

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #btn_s{
            width:100px;
        }

        #btn_i {
            width:125px;
        }
        #formbox {
            width:400px;
            margin:auto 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div id="formbox">
            <input value="Search" title="Search" type="submit" id="btn_s"> 
            <input value="I'm Feeling Lucky" title="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="lucky" type="submit" id="btn_i">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This has 2 examples, you can use the one that fits best in your situation.

- use `text-align:center` on the parent container, or create a container for this.
- if the container has to have a fixed size, use `auto` left and right margins to center it in the parent container.

note that `auto` is used with single blocks to center them in the parent space by distrubuting the empty space to the left and right.

Answer (score 4):

```
/* here is what works for me - set up as a class */

.button {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* you can set padding and width to whatever works best */
```

Comment: Gah... `display: block`... always forget that!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the buttons are supposed to be next to each other on the same line, they should not each be centered using the 'auto' margin, but placed inside a div with a defined width that has a margin '0 auto':

CSS:

```
#centerbuttons{
   width:250px; 
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML (after removing the margin properties from your buttons' CSS):

```
<div id="centerbuttons">
     <input value="Search" title="Search" type="submit"> 
     <input value="I'm Feeling Lucky" title="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="lucky" type="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
form div {
    width: 400px;   
    border: 1px solid black;
} 

form input[type='submit']  {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
}

div.submitWrapper  {
   text-align: center;    
}    
</style>
<form>

<div class='submitWrapper'>    
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> 
 </div>
```

Also Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaziSyd/V63nB/13/)

Comment: You need to set the margin on the button as well. margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution if only one button needs to be centered is something like:

```
<input type='submit' style='display:flex; justify-content:center;' value='Submit'>
```

Although I've used an inline example, for production, [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72560521/5362795) should be placed in a CSS file using  [a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics).

Comment: Ummm, bad practice to use inline JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I used this for an internal tool, not in production, and I just wanted a quick solution. Mostly programming in C and Python at the time. Please go ahead and delete the answer, I click on “delete” but nothing happens...

Comment: I think I remember why I chose this, the temporary internal tool I wrote used python CGI to write dynamic HTML, so the requirement was essentially as short as possible in one line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take it to the next level, use **flexbox**:

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1em;
}
#btn_s {
  width: 100px;
}
#btn_i {
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input value="Search" title="Search" type="submit" id="btn_s">
  <input value="I'm Feeling Lucky" title="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="lucky" type="submit" id="btn_i">
</div>
```

Guide to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `text-align: center`.

```css
.form-1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#btn_s {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#btn_i {
  width: 125px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-1">
  <input value="Search" title="Search" type="submit" id="btn_s">
  <input value="I'm Feeling Lucky" title="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="lucky" type="submit" id="btn_i">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are by default an `inline-block` style element. They will not respond to auto. You have to indicate a specific number.

```
button {
  margin: 6px 50px;
}
```

(I prefer percentages, they seem to work better)

If, in the case, it must respond to `margin: auto`, you have to change it to be a block element.

```
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 6px auto;
}
```