# CSS floating issue id div

Tags: css, grid

How could I centralize all the elements vertically and horizontally?
I tried to fix the div placement horizontally by using CSS float but it too disturbing for me now. Does there any perfect and useful solution. Please help me. I also want them in center

Answer (score -1):

Using

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

should work to keep everything centered.
For more detailed answer go here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217315/html-css-content-always-centered#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20elements%20always,in%20the%20styles%20on%20it.&text=To%20get%20background%20elements%20to,the%20same%20style%20as%20above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217315/html-css-content-always-centered#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20elements%20always,in%20the%20styles%20on%20it.&text=To%20get%20background%20elements%20to,the%20same%20style%20as%20above).

Answer (score -1):

take a parant div and set it css

```
    div {
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;

         }
```

if don't work just

```
           div{
                margin:auto;
              }
```