# How do I center a button that's not in a DIV element?

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" 
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">
```

I can't put it in a DIV element or else it will not function properly so I was wondering how I could center this button.

EDIT: here's my overall code for the webpage : https://jsfiddle.net/n0ya9tbq/

The reason why I can't put it in a DIV element is because I'm using Google Apps Script and in GAS if I put it in a div element i encounter this error : [google.script.run not working: Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680509/google-script-run-not-working-uncaught-invalidargumenterror-failed-due-to-ille)

Comment: You typically center inline and inline block elements by centering the content *of its parent*.

Comment: In any case, we'd need more code / a full (but *minimal*, e.g. the `onclick` code doesn't seem relevant?) repro of your scenario. It would also help if you share your attempts and research: there's quite a few ways to go about this, depending on the context one solution might be preferable to the other.

Comment: The onclick may be relevant, he says it won't function in a div... why not?

Comment: Centering happens on the **parent** object. So, without any real parent other than the `body` tag, this can be hard. Also, why wouldn't the functionality work if it was placed inside of a `div`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center form submit buttons html / css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221263/center-form-submit-buttons-html-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include an ID in the input tag
    `<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" id='centeredbutton' class='buttoncenter'
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">`

Then use css:

```
`input#centeredbutton {
position: fixed;
bottom: 50%;
right: 50%;
}`
```

Or if you have multiple buttons you want centered:

```
`input.buttoncenter {
position: fixed;
bottom: 50%;
right: 50%;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it changing the display property

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" 
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">
```

Comment: Works fine without the fixed width, too.

Comment: yep, you just need to change the `display` property. Please, accept my answer!

Comment: this centers the button based on the page size but not the container's width size though. If I minimize the page or zoom out of it, the button placement is changed.

Comment: You can set the width in pixel instead of percentage...
Of course if you set `width: 50%;` the button width is based on its parent that represents the 100%...

Comment: having the width changes the size of the button not where the button is located, that's whats happening for me